"runfile" not aware of changes to *.py file until I open it in Spyder editor
I have recently started to become familiar with the Spyder editor as a debugger.  For purposes other than for debugging, however, I use my favourite external editor (Vim for me, but probably Emacs for others).  I am working on a MyScript.py script that is not meant to be a module, in the sense that I don't define functions.  I am simply experimenting with and growing some code as a script.  I run the script with runfile.
Before today, any changes to MyScript.py made with Vim would be reflected in the console output and Variable Explorer  when I issued runfile.  As of today, any changes made to MyScript.py is not reflected in console output and Variable Explorer.  I cannot find any setting in Preferences that determines whether runfile('MyScript.py') refreshes its copy of MyScript.py before it executes the statements therein.  The newest MyScript.py isn't seen even if I exit with Ctrl+D, which simply makes the console reconnect to a (hopefully new) kernel.
What could possibly have caused this behaviour today and not previously?  How can I get the old behaviour back, i.e., changes made to MyScript.py by an external editor are recognized by runfile('MyScript.py')?  I am using Spyder 5.4.3 wit Python 3.9, installed on Windows 10 with Anaconda.
Afternote: If I open the file in Spyder's editor, it picks up the changes.  If I make further changes in Vim, however, they aren't automatically detected.  However, if I click in the Spyder editor, the change in focus seems to force it to pick up the latest changes.  Since I'm otherwise not using the Spyder editor, I would prefer to use the real estate for the Console window or the Variable Explorer.  Unfortunately, I can only shrink the width so much and there is significant width still taken up by the editor.
Since this behaviour started recently, I suspect that Spyder or IPython may cache the *.py file if it has a size that is greater than some threshold.  As I develop the file, it crosses this speculated threshold.

maybe you have two files MyScript.py (in different places/folders) and you run one file in vim but other in Spyder. To make sure use /full/path/to/MyScript.py

Yes, they are one file.  I added an afternote to my question to indicate the events that trigger a sync of the editor to the file.
